# BCP in SQL Server 2008 : can not find stored procedure 'sp_describe_first_result_set'

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, bcp

My `.bcp` file was out from SQL Server 2016.

When I attempted `bcp` in SQL Server 2008 R2, an error occurred:

> SQLState = 37000, NativeError = 2812
>   Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Could not find stored procedure 'sp_describe_first_result_set'

Can anyone give me some idea?

Comment: Most likely some incompatibility between output from SS16 versus SS08. Also we'd need more information to give input on this issue. The commands used for export and import, and a sample output file.

Comment: There's a potentially similar issues described on Connect here: [Attempt to use BCP 2016 to export from SQL 2008 or earlier fails with obscure error message](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/2777154/attempt-to-use-bcp-2016-to-export-from-sql-2008-or-earlier-fails-with-obscure-error-message).

Comment: according @3N1GM4 support , I resolve this problem , just download [windows odbc driver](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=50420)

Answer (score 6):

There's a potentially similar issue described on Connect here: [Attempt to use BCP 2016 to export from SQL 2008 or earlier fails with obscure error message](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/2777154/attempt-to-use-bcp-2016-to-export-from-sql-2008-or-earlier-fails-with-obscure-error-message).

Try downloading the [Windows ODBC driver](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=50420).

Answer (score 2):

I changed my location to bcp.exe at version 110 and ran ok

```
cd  C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn
cp <commands>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's funny but

```
bcp "$db$..$table$" out $file$.csv -c -t\t -T -S $server$
```

fails with the error.

> SQLState = 37000, NativeError = 2812
>   Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Could not find stored procedure 'sp_describe_first_result_set'.

But this works OK:

```
bcp "select * from $table$" queryout $file$.csv -d $db$ -c -t\t -T -S $server$
```

Server is sql 2008, and client is Version: 13.0.1601.5.

Comment: it's really strange

Comment: In my case, I also have bcp.exe from SQL 2008. (under 100\Tools\Binn folder). This version ran OK without the error.